# Auto scale by CPU usage not working in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, autoscaling

I have tried to modify the AutoScale configuration in Azure. But that configuration not updated.

**Note:** Auto Scale is ON mode.

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add more details about your configuration. Otherwise we can only guess.